# Player Movement with Velocity

Tags: c#, game-physics

I have a little question. I have a script that I attach to a GameObject and with it I can control the object up and down at a certain speed. I want the movement to be a little inertia, that is, to be more real. This is my code:

```
float moveSpeed = 5f;
void Update()
{
    float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(0, y).normalized;
    Move(direction);
}

void Move(Vector2 direction)
{
    Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0));
    Vector2 max = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(1, 1));
    Vector2 pos = transform.position;       
    pos += direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, min.y, max.y);
    transform.position = pos;       
}
```

This code works but seems unreal, it would be good to add some inertia or velocity. Help please!

Comment: (I'm guessing this is Unity) There are several ways to do this. Simplest one would be to increase the speed not in an instance but with `Mathf.MoveTowards`. E.g. keep track of the current speed and whenever the `direction` changes, change another, intermediate value *towards* that new value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change velocity, you need to change moveSpeed (which is your velocity), not just direction.

```
float moveSpeed = 0f;
// modify this to change how your intertia looks like
float frictionValue = 1f;
void Update()
{
  float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
  moveSpeed += y * Time.deltaTime;
  Move();
  moveSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(moveSpeed, 0f, frictionValue * Time.deltaTime); 
}
void Move()
{
  Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0));
  Vector2 max = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(1, 1));
  Vector2 pos = transform.position;       
  pos.y += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
  pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, min.y, max.y);
  transform.position = pos;       
}
```

Comment: I can't put my finger on it, but something about this feels wrong. Wouldn't `Mathf.Clamp(moveSpeed, 0f, frictionValue * Time.deltaTime)` reduce the max speed based on the frame rate? (@60fps 0.016)

Comment: It is not supposed to depend on a frame rate, that's why we multiply friction by Time.deltaTime.

Comment: Exactly, since the speed is multiplied by Time.deltaTime in Move **again** that would result in lower speed overall when the framerate is higher, wouldn't it? If it was `Mathf.MoveTowards` I'd say it looks right, but if you clamp it ... What I'm trying to say is - This doesn't seem to slow down the acceleration but only limit the max speed.

Comment: `Mathf.MoveTowards(moveSpeed,0,friction * Time.deltaTime)` would be correct imho, and should be applied **before** `Move()`. The way it is now `moveSpeed` can be between `-1` and `1 + frictionValue * Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: There is no maxSpeed in my code. It is only a current speed. That's why it does not actually make any real difference if we slow down before or after Move().

Comment: But you've spotted a problem indeed. It was supposed to be Mathf.Lerp, not Mathf.Clamp. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Uhm ... I think that would make it even worse but glad I could help.

Comment: private Rigidbody2D rb;

Comment: rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

Comment: float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector2(0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.AddForce(movement * moveSpeed);

Comment: @Giku `AddForce` is in Newtons and takes the `Weight` and `Drag` of your Rigidbody into account.

Answer (score 1):

Should be an easy fix:

Instead of accelerating from 0 to moveSpeed instantly, use `Vector2.MoveTowards` to slowly accelerate towards your target speed.

```
public float moveSpeed = 5f;
public float acceleration = 1f;
private Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;

void Update()
{
    float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(0, y).normalized;
    Move(direction);
}

void Move(Vector2 direction)
{
    moveDirection = Vector2.MoveTowards(moveDirection, direction, 
        acceleration * Time.deltaTime);

    Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0));
    Vector2 max = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(1, 1));
    Vector2 pos = transform.position;
    pos += moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    //pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, min.y, max.y);
    transform.position = pos;
}
```